How can I group by a single field in mongo?
Two part question

I would like to group records by a single field.

then retrieve user information


I would like to group by the REF_NotifierID field.
Here is the data.
[
{
  "_id": "66d90957373dd9d5c85d503c",
  "REF_NotifierID": "66d9070f373dd9d5c85d5034",
  "REF_UserID": "66c8fbb1a97fee2ae10a3d81",
},
{
  "_id": "66d90a33373dd9d5c85d5050",
  "REF_NotifierID": "66d90700373dd9d5c85d502e",
  "REF_UserID": "66c8fbb1a97fee2ae10a3d81",
},
{
  "_id": "66d9ca6be74061bbd0d1996a",
  "REF_NotifierID": "66d90700373dd9d5c85d502e",
  "REF_UserID":"66d9c3ddc1d6fcc235ccc92e",
}
]

Part 1
Here is what I have tried... didn't work :-(
$group : {
  REF_NotifierID: {
    $first: "$REF_NotifierID",
    $users: "REF_UserID",
  }
}

This is the only data that I would like to have returned and in this structure:
{
  "notifiers": [
    {
      "REF_NotifierID": "66d9070f373dd9d5c85d5034",
      "users": [
        {
          "REF_UserID": "66c8fbb1a97fee2ae10a3d81"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "REF_NotifierID": "66d90700373dd9d5c85d502e",
      "users": [
        {
          "REF_UserID": "66c8fbb1a97fee2ae10a3d81"
        },
        {
          "REF_UserID": "66d9c3ddc1d6fcc235ccc92e"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

thanks to @cmgchesss !  this groups correctly
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$REF_NotifierID",
      "users": {
        "$addToSet": {
          "REF_UserID": "$REF_UserID"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "notifiers": {
        "$push": {
          "REF_NotifierID": "$_id",
          "users": "$users"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": "_id"
  }

Part 2
I would like to get the user information from the grouped results
I have tried a lookup
    $lookup: {
      from: 'users',
      localField: 'REF_UserID',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'testusers',
    },

this is what I get:
[
        {
            "notifiers": [
                {
                    "REF_NotifierID": "66d9070f373dd9d5c85d5034",
                    "users": [
                        {
                            "REF_UserID": "66c8fbb1a97fee2ae10a3d81"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "REF_NotifierID": "66d90700373dd9d5c85d502e",
                    "users": [
                        {
                            "REF_UserID": "66c8fbb1a97fee2ae10a3d81"
                        },
                        {
                            "REF_UserID": "66d9c3ddc1d6fcc235ccc92e"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "testusers": []
        }
    ]

I'd like to have the REF_UserID augmented with the user's firstName, LastName fields from the user table.
eg:
{
"REF_UserID": "66d9c3ddc1d6fcc235ccc92e",
"firstName": "Fred",
"lastName" : "Jones",
}


somehting like this maybe https://mongoplayground.net/p/cLAQ7li1ygm

https://stackoverflow.com/users/13583510/cmgchess - super... thank you that works to group... but how can I get the additional user data now ??  ( I have updated question )

many ways to do but i guess easier if lookup done before group  . https://mongoplayground.net/p/RVv6VA45shc .

You can use $documents inside a lookup stage to perform a separate lookup into the users collection for each element in the array.
Steps in this pipeline:

group by notifier, push user ids into an array of objects
lookup with no collection, specifying the the array of user ids as the initial documents
embedded lookup against the users collection to retrieve the desired data from each user record (note the duplication of the REF_UserId to simplify combining documents later)
unwind the embedded lookup result so it is an object instead of array
replace the original users array entry with the looked up data.

db.notifier.aggregate([
  {$group: {
      _id: "$REF_NotifierID",
      users: {$push: {REF_UserID: "$REF_UserID"}}
  }},
  {$lookup: {
      let: {docs: "$users"},
      as: "users",
      pipeline: [
        {$documents: "$$docs"},
        {$lookup: {
            from: "users",
            localField: "REF_UserID",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "userData",
            pipeline: [
              {$project: {
                  _id: 0,
                  firstname: 1,
                  lastname: 1,
                  REF_UserID: "$_id"
              }}
            ]
        }},
        {$unwind: "$userData"        },
        {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$userData"}}
      ]
  }}
])

Example: Playground
